# How to add points to grid in python

Tags: python, css, grid

So i have a code that creates a grid (its a bit long)

```
width = int(input('Enter the width: '))
height = int(input('Enter the height: '))

# print the grid

# prints y-axel
y = 1
print('  ', end='')
for x in range(0, width):
    print(y, end='')
    y = y + 1
    if y == 10:
        y = 0
print('')

print(' +', '-' * (width), sep='')  # prints the top row
# prints all remaining x-axels
z = 1
for i in range(0, height):
    print(z, '|', '.' * width, sep='')
    z = z + 1
    if z == 10:
        z = 0

# ask do you wanna put a point in a grid
point = input('Shall we add a point (Y/N)? ')
if point == 'Y' or point == 'y':
    x_coord = int(input('Enter X-coordinate: '))
    y_coord = int(input('Enter Y-coordinate: '))

    # prints y-axel
    y = 1
    print('  ', end='')
    for x in range(0, width):
        print(y, end='')
        y = y + 1
        if y == 10:
            y = 0
    print('')

    # prints all remaing x-axels
    print(' +', '-' * (width), sep='')
    z = 1
    for i in range(0, height):
        if i != (y_coord - 1):
            print(z, '|', '.' * (width), sep='')

        if i == (y_coord - 1):
            print(z, '|', '.' * (x_coord - 1), 'X', '.' * (width - x_coord),
                  sep='')  # add the point
        z = z + 1
        if z == 10:
            z = 0
```

Which will print a grid where you can decide its width and height. And where you can add points to a grid. For example grid (width=15 and height=5) gives you a grid that looks like:

```
Enter the width: 15
Enter the height: 5
  123456789012345
 +---------------
1|...............
2|...............
3|...............
4|...............
5|...............
```

after that you can add X-points to the grid that you made like

```
Shall we add a point (Y/N)? y
Enter X-coordinate: 13
Enter Y-coordinate: 2
  123456789012345
 +---------------
1|...............
2|............X..
3|...............
4|...............
5|...............
```

after that comes my problem. I dont know how to save this X-point so it would remain on the grid. After that i should be available to add new X-points to the grid. So if i wanted to add new X-point to (2,2) it would look like

```
Shall we add a point (Y/N)? y
Enter X-coordinate: 2
Enter Y-coordinate: 2
  123456789012345
 +---------------
1|...............
2|.X..........X..
3|...............
4|...............
5|...............
```

so basically my problem is that i dont know how to save changes to my grid.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can store grid point coordinates in a list. The code you have isn't very adaptable. For example you have two separate blocks of code that print out the grid. One that prints an empty grid and another that prints it with a single point. You really need to have one block of code that prints the grid regardless of how many points there are. This probably means printing grid co-ords one at a time every time in a loop and check each time to see if the current coordinate pair is in the list, and if so print an 'X'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep a list of previous X co-ordinates.

## Explanation

Python has a [list](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm) data type.

You can add items to a list, ad you can check to see if items are in the list already.

The following demonstrates how lists work:

```
points = []
print(points)
if [1,2] in points:
    print("Found you")
else:
    print("It isn't here")

points.append([1,2])
points.append([5,6])
points.append([7,3])
print(points)
if [1,2] in points:
    print("Found you")
else:
    print("It isn't here")
```

It gives this output:

```
[]
It isn't here
[[1, 2], [5, 6], [7, 3]]
Found you
```

## Fix your code

I have amended your code and commented to show you how:

```
width = int(input('Enter the width: '))
height = int(input('Enter the height: '))

# print the grid

# prints y-axel
y = 1
print('  ', end='')
for x in range(0, width):
    print(y, end='')
    y = y + 1
    if y == 10:
        y = 0
print('')

print(' +', '-' * (width), sep='')  # prints the top row
# prints all remaining x-axels
z = 1
for i in range(0, height):
    print(z, '|', '.' * width, sep='')
    z = z + 1
    if z == 10:
        z = 0

# this is a list of all the xpoints
xpoints = []

# Keep asking until the user says no
while True:
    # ask do you wanna put a point in a grid
    point = input('Shall we add a point (Y/N)? ')
    if point == 'Y' or point == 'y':
        x_coord = int(input('Enter X-coordinate: '))
        y_coord = int(input('Enter Y-coordinate: '))
        xpoints.append([x_coord, y_coord])  # add the new point to the list

        # prints y-axel
        y = 1
        print('  ', end='')
        for x in range(0, width):
            print(y, end='')
            y = y + 1
            if y == 10:
                y = 0
        print('')

        # prints all remaining x-axels
        print(' +', '-' * (width), sep='')
        z = 1
        # for every row
        for i in range(0, height):
            line = str(z)+"|" # This string will hold the line as we add dots to it
            # for every point in the row
            for x in range(width):
                # if this point is an X point:
                if [x, i] in xpoints:
                    line += 'X'
                # if it isn't:
                else:
                    line += '.'
            print(line) # Show the line
            z = z + 1
            if z == 10:
                z = 0
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Your code was correct except that the X-point always went to (x+1,y+1). So it went 1 too much in both axels. So i only had to fix `if [x, i] in xpoints:` to `if [x+1, i+1] in xpoints:`

Comment: Depends whether you `0` or `1` index your arrays. But yes, you UI was `1` indexed, I should have seen that :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a list of lists as your grid and change the according element at index [y][x] to 'X' when the user enters something.

```
grid = [['-' for i in range(9)] for j in range(7)]

y = 5
x = 3
# Note that y comes first.
grid[y][x] = 'X'

for row in grid:
    for item in row:
        print(item, end='')
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your grid is a 2D array:

```
width = int(input('Enter the width: '))
height = int(input('Enter the height: '))

grid = []
for i in range(height):
    grid.append(['.']*width)

def print_grid(grid):
    # Header: '  123456789012345'
    print('  ', end='')
    for i in range(width):
        print(i%10, end='')
    print('')  # New line
    # Table: ' +---------------'
    print(' +', end='')
    for i in range(width):
        print('-', end='')
    print('')  # New line
    # Rows
    for i, row in enumerate(grid):
        print(str(i) + '|', end='')
        for cell in row:
            print(cell, end='')
        print('')  # New line

def fill_grid(grid, x, y):
    grid[y-1][x-1] = 'X'
```

Usage:

```
fill_grid(grid, 13, 3)
print_grid(grid)
```